# How to solve math quadratic world problem?

Tags: quadratics, word-problem

The question is

The big brick bakery sells more bagels when it reduces its prices, but then its profit changes. The function
$$y=−1000(x−0.55)^2+300$$
models the bakery's profit (in dollars) from selling bagels, where x is the price of a bagel in dollars. The bakery wants to maximize the profit.

The main question is.

1) What price should the bakery charge to maximize its profit from bagels?

For this I don't even know where to start it does not give me any numbers to plug on or anything. How do I find it? How do i start this?

Answer (score 2):

Logically, $-1000\left( x-0.55 \right)^{2}$ is always negative or equal to zero; never positive because of the square and the sign on the outside. So you want $-1000\left( x-0.55 \right)^{2}$ to be zero, not negative, to maximise the profit; find $x$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, You said to make −1000(x−0.55)2 to zero..what do you mean by making it zero? like the whole  thing to zero than how do i find "x"??

Comment: Exactly, you make the whole thing zero, x=0.55

Comment: that's because any higher or lower value of x will make the whole thing negative, and that won't maximise ur profit

Comment: Ohhh thanks a lot..The problem was really frustrating...thanks a lot man...